# How to fix my brew doctor errors

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew on my Mac so I can use PPSSPP, but I received a load of problems before finishing installation. How do I fix the unexpected things I have? Somebody please help.

**Warning:** gettext files detected at a system prefix
These files can cause compilation and link failures, especially if they
are compiled with improper architectures. Consider removing these files:

```
/usr/local/lib/libintl.dylib
```

**Warning:** Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

**Unexpected dylibs:**

```
/usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.0.2209.1.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.0.1200.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.0.1200.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.0.1200.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgio-2.0.0.0.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libGLEW.1.5.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.0.1600.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgmodule-2.0.0.1600.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.1600.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgthread-2.0.0.1600.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.0.1200.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libintl.8.0.2.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.62.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libpango-1.0.0.2100.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.0.2100.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.0.2100.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libpangox-1.0.0.2100.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libpangoxft-1.0.0.2100.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libportaudio.2.0.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libz.1.2.5.dylib
```

**Warning:** Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

**Unexpected .la files:**

```
/usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libgio-2.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libglib-2.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libgmodule-2.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libgobject-2.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libgthread-2.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libintl.la
/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.la
/usr/local/lib/libpango-1.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libpangox-1.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libpangoxft-1.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libportaudio.la
```

**Warning:** Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

**Unexpected static libraries:**

```
/usr/local/lib/libGLEW.a
/usr/local/lib/libintl.a
/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a
/usr/local/lib/libportaudio.a
/usr/local/lib/libz.a
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete all unexpected files and run `brew doctor` again.

If everything is ok run then `brew update`.

Beware that if you have installed another package manager using the same location, this can break things.